# how to use axios to sign in with OAuth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, oauth-2.0

I just started learning MERN stack last week with Brad Traversy's MERN course: https://www.udemy.com/mern-stack-front-to-back/
In the course, he separated front-end and back-end and use back-end as REST API. In the back-end, he has a POST route (/api/auth) that returns a JWT token and the API is used in the react app axios. Then, the response is used for the value of the header x-auth-token, so that the authentication middleware could help to authenticate. As an computer science newbie working as an internship right now, I am required to make a web app for my company for internal use which uses slack OAuth for authentication. Now here is the problem: when I use axios, the response is some HTML codes like this:

```
GET https://slack.com/oauth/authorize? 
scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar&client_id=48321353297.675712837139 in postman, result:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
    'gtm.start': Date.now(),
    'event' : 'gtm.js',
    'secure_page' : false,
});
var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var thisScript = document.createElement('script');
thisScript.async = true;
thisScript.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KH2LPK';
firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(thisScript, firstScript);
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var gtmDataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    var gtmTags = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-gtm-click]');
    var gtmClickHandler = function(c) {
        var gtm_events = this.getAttribute('data-gtm-click');
        if (!gtm_events) return;
        var gtm_events_arr = gtm_events.split(",");
        for(var e=0; e < gtm_events_arr.length; e++) {
            var ev = gtm_events_arr[e].trim();
            gtmDataLayer.push({ 'event': ev });
        }
    };
    for(var g=0; g < gtmTags.length; g++){
        var elem = gtmTags[g];
        elem.addEventListener('click', gtmClickHandler);
    }
});

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
(function(e,c,b,f,d,g,a){e.SlackBeaconObject=d;
e[d]=e[d]||function(){(e[d].q=e[d].q||[]).push([1*new Date(),arguments])};
e[d].l=1*new Date();g=c.createElement(b);a=c.getElementsByTagName(b)[0];
g.async=1;g.src=f;a.parentNode.insertBefore(g,a)
})(window,document,"script","https://a.slack-edge.com/bv1-6-8cacda2/slack_beacon.bc058f2eca7b7d633d5a.min.js","sb");
window.sb('set', 'token', '3307f436963e02d4f9eb85ce5159744c');
sb('set', 'user_' + "batch", "signup_api");sb('set', 'user_' + "created", "2019-06-03");sb('set', 'user_id', "UK781P40Y");
sb('set', 'name_tag', "wemine" + '/' + "klaus.chau");
window.sb('track', 'pageview');
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "https:\/\/slack.com\/oauth\/authorize?scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar&client_id=48321353297.675712837139&tracked=1";</script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is that it is sending me the 'confirm login page' instead of the jwt token I needed from the redirectURI.
Would it be possible for me to implement like what Brad did in the course even though I am not logging in with password and email?
Thanks
Resources that could be referenced:
https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0/blob/master/routes/api/auth.js
https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0/blob/master/client/src/actions/auth.js
https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector_2.0/blob/master/client/src/reducers/auth.js

Comment: lookup `passportjs` and related strategies (slack strategy for example)

Comment: Hi Aritra, I have tried to implement it in my code but still, I was wondering how could one use axios to get data from a link that is different from the original one (e.g. I would like to call GET api/auth and get the return data from api/auth/redirect). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot `Ajax`(`axios` or `request` or `XMLHttprequest`) to get the OAuth or any external auth tokens. Because here is the flow,

1. You click a `login` button
2. Goes to the passport(or any auth) route.
3. The auth provider redirects to the original OAuth provider(like fb, google, slack etc)
4. You login THERE, in THEIR SITE.
5. It redirects back to another route of your passport application that decrypts the request body and gets the token.
6. It returns the token.

So basically for the redirection (step 3) to work, you need to redirect or a href to the passport route(which will be a GET route) which will inturn redirect to google/fb/slack.

Hope you understood why you cannot use Ajax to fetch from external authentication providers.

Comment: If it helped please accept the answer by clicking the gray tick